# Max function of a column that is not a table in db, sql

Tags: sql

Sorry if the title is confusing. When I run a particular query I get one column of `count(something)`-s. And I want to get the maximum value of that column. I'll explain in example:

```
select count(isbn)
from wrote
group by idWritter
```

So this returns one column, something like this:

```
+-----------+
count(isbn)
+-----------+
1
5
22
4
+-----------+
```

and I want 22. So how to do that?

Comment: I hope now is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, did you try `MAX()` ?

```
SELECT MAX(isbn) FROM wrote GROUP BY idWritter;
```

Or (as I understand now):

```
SELECT MAX(c) FROM (SELECT COUNT(isbn) AS c FROM wrote GROUP BY idWritter) A;
```

Comment: I tryed 
`max(
select count(isbn)
from wrote
group by idWritter
)` which gives me error..

Answer (score 1):

Hoping, i understood correctly.

Please check

```
select max(cnt) from
(
select idWritter , count(isbn) cnt
from wrote
group by idWritter
);
```

Comment: Not exactly, i want maximum out of all count(isbn) values that this query returns.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirmation. query updated please check now

Answer (score 1):

You can select the max of the count this way

```
 select max(t.my_value) 
 from (
    select count(isbn) as my_value
    from wrote
   group by idWritter
 ) t
```